# FullCalendar rendering strangely

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twig

I've been trying to incorporate FullCalendar into my Symfony2.3 project. It seems like it's working fine, however I just have one very strange issue - the events all render at the top left hand corner, all the time (for all the different views). Has anybody experienced this and perhaps have a fix? My code is below, I have not touched the default CSS and JS files.

Here's what the calendar renders:

[image]

Here is the JS and HTML in my view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  

 $('#timetable').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        handleWindowResize: true,
        events: '{{ path('
        calendar_get_json_data ') }}'
    });

});

</script>
<div id="timetable"></div>
```

And finally the JSON response from my event URL above (which is converted to '/app_dev.php/timetable/fetch' by the way)

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test\/Exam",
    "start": "2013-11-12 16:00",
    "end": "2013-11-13 18:00",
    "url": "\/app_dev.php\/testevent\/1\/show"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Test\/Exam",
    "start": "2013-11-13 06:00",
    "end": "2013-11-20 00:00",
    "url": "\/app_dev.php\/testevent\/2\/show"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Test\/Exam",
    "start": "2013-11-08 10:00",
    "end": "2013-11-12 00:00",
    "url": "\/app_dev.php\/testevent\/3\/show"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Test\/Exam",
    "start": "2013-11-12 10:00",
    "end": "2013-11-12 19:00",
    "url": "\/app_dev.php\/testevent\/4\/show"
}]
```

Everything seems to be working fine (the correct JSON data is returned, I can click and view the links, etc) but the rendering is just so strange? I must be missing something random.

Thanks for any assist!

PS I tried returning the JSON feed in the 'Y-m-d' format (without 'H:i') but this still didn't solve the issue.

**EDIT -**

I've tried making a template with only the timetable on it and this seems to work fine. It must then be conflicting with bootstrap or the chosen library (for selects). Does anybody have any ideas as to what could be the conflict and how to resolve it?

Comment: First you should figure out whether this is an HTML/DOM issue, or a CSS (formatting) issue – do the items get rendered into the right cells in the DOM? How are they formated, any absolute positioning involved?

Comment: It seems like the events are in the DOM correctly, but the styles seem off. I wonder if it could be because I'm loading this section into another section? Would that throw anything out? The styles on all elements rendered look a little like this: `position: absolute; left: 2px; width: 81px; top: 2px;`, just with the left being either 0 or 2. Very weird.

Comment: I had also encountered a similar situation once but later I recognized it was because of one of the additional file `fullcalendar.print.css`. It was provided to make it more printing friendly. You might also have forgotten to use the `media='print'` attribute of the <link> tag.